# How to bind image in crystal report?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports-2010

I'm trying to add a picture in the Crystal Report but, when I add it all of the Crystal Report doesn't loads and gives the following error:

> Failed to enable constrains one or more raw's contain value violating non-null.unique.all foreign key constraints.

Comment: This is not an issue of Report Image, check the data coming for the report, may be there is some exception

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in removing the key from table adapted at the dataset.